# Breaking out of a loop, so as to not include a value

Tags: java, while-loop

I have a question about how to break out of a loop so as not to include a value. I am supposed to enter a few integer amounts to represent grades on a test and then break out of the loop when a value of "0" is entered. However I do not want 0 to be included in the calculation of the average and the minimum. That is a little vague so here is my code.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;

public class Grades
{
   public static void main (String[] args)
   {  
      Scanner myScan= new Scanner(System.in);

      String input="Input numerical grade:";
      System.out.println(input);



      int sum=0;
      int count= 0;
      int max= 0;
      int min= 0;
      double avg=0; 

      boolean notNull= true;


      while(notNull== true)//While grades are greater than 0 ask the question again

         {
         int grade= myScan.nextInt();
         if(grade==0)break;

              if(grade>max)
              {
               max=grade;
              }

              if(grade<min)
              {

               min=grade;
              }

              System.out.println(input);
               sum +=grade;
               count++;
               avg= (sum)/(count);
            }


            System.out.println("Maximum:"+max);
            System.out.println("Minimum:"+min);
            System.out.println("Average:"+avg);



          }




      }
```

And here is my return when I enter a few random test scores and 0. So instead of 0 I want my minimum to be 47.

```
 ----jGRASP exec: java Grades

Input numerical grade:
89
Input numerical grade:
47
Input numerical grade:
78
Input numerical grade:
0
Maximum:89
Minimum:0
Average:71.0

 ----jGRASP: operation complete.
```

Comment: Fix your tabbing so we can tell what's in and outside of your loop as is... and instead of using a boolean, you can just do `while(true)`...

Comment: What you have should work, though it's impossible to sort out for sure with the poor indentation.  Your problem is initializing "min" to zero -- always init the "min" value to a large number.

Comment: Whoever downvoted every answer should really leave a comment explaining why.

Comment: I downvoted Blaine's answer with an explanation.  I don't know about the other downvotes on the answers that are actually correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `0` your program is printing out isn't the `0` the user enters.  It's the `0` you initialize `min` to.  (Currently, your `average` is being properly calculated.)

```
if(grade<min)
{
     min=grade;
}
```

`min`'s original value is `0`.  So unless you're taking negative grades, `grade<min` will never evaluate to `true`.

Instead of `int min = 0;`, you should do this:

```
int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
```

Also, as I commented, because you're never touching the `boolean` you use as the `while loop` conditional check, and you're only wanting to exit the loop when the user enters `0`, you can just drop the entire variable, and use `while(true)`.

Answer (score 1):

You don-t take into account that you've initialized min with zero so:

```
if(grade<min)
{
     min=grade;
}
```

will never change `min`because it is already minimal non-negative integer - zero.

So take this into account with following condition:

```
if(min == 0 || min < grade)
{
     min=grade;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're already breaking out of your loop before processing the `0`. The reason your minimum is 0 is because you initialized it to 0, and so of course `if (grade<min) { min=grade; }` will never happen for any positive `grade`.

You have a few options:

- You could set `min = max = grade` directly for the first grade that is input.
- You could initialize `min` to a large number that any reasonable grade would be less than, e.g. `Integer.MAX_VALUE`.

You have a few possibilities for an implementation of the first option. You could store some `first` flag that you initialize to true then set to false. You could maintain a count of the number of grades input and initialize min/max when the count is 0 (or 1 depending on how you do it). You could initialize min/max to some special flag values that a grade could never be, e.g. -1, and set them to `grade` directly when they equal that flag value.

The point here is that the reason you are seeing 0 for your minimum isn't because you're processing that final 0, it's because you initialize your minimum to 0, and no grade is lower than that.

Comment: Jason, I don't know who downvotes our answers, but I'll upvote yours.

Comment: I upvoted yours too! Now we're upvote buddies! Because upvotes are important!

Answer (score 0):

You probably want somthing like this:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Grades {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner myScan = new Scanner(System.in);

        String input = "Input numerical grade:";

        System.out.println(input);
        int grade = myScan.nextInt();

        int sum = 0;
        int count = 0;
        int max = grade;
        int min = grade;
        double avg = grade;

        while (grade != 0) {

            if (grade > max) {
                max = grade;
            }

            if (grade < min) {
                min = grade;
            }

            count++;
            sum += grade;
            avg = (sum) / (count);

            System.out.println(input);
            grade = myScan.nextInt();

        }

        System.out.println("Maximum:" + max);
        System.out.println("Minimum:" + min);
        System.out.println("Average:" + avg);

    }

}
```

Puts out:

```
Input numerical grade:
89
Input numerical grade:
47
Input numerical grade:
78
Input numerical grade:
0
Maximum:89
Minimum:47
Average:71.0
```